# In OpenMDAO can I use set_check_partial_options to prevent certain derivatives from being checked?

Tags: derivative, openmdao

I have an `om.ExplicitComponent` in which some of the derivatives are exact (analytic) and can be checked with the complex step method (`cs`), some of the derivatives are analytic but cannot be checked with `cs`, and some which can only be evaluated with finite differences.

```
import openmdao.api as om

from scipy.special import ellipe, ellipk
from scipy.special import hyp2f1

class MWE(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input("a")
        self.add_input("b")
        self.add_input("c")
        self.add_output("x")
        self.add_output("y")
        self.add_output("z")

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        a = inputs["a"]
        b = inputs["b"]
        c = inputs["c"]
        outputs["x"] = a**2
        outputs["y"] = ellipe(b)
        outputs["z"] = hyp2f1(1 / 10, a, 1 / 2, c)

    def setup_partials(self):
        self.declare_partials("x", ["a"], method="exact")
        self.declare_partials("y", ["b"], method="exact")
        self.declare_partials("z", ["a"], method="fd")
        self.declare_partials("z", ["c"], method="exact")

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, J):
        a = inputs["a"]
        b = inputs["b"]
        c = inputs["c"]
        J["x", "a"] = 2 * a

        J["y", "b"] = (ellipe(b) - ellipk(b)) / (2 * b)

        J["z", "c"] = (a / 5) * hyp2f1(11 / 10, 1 + a, 3 / 2, c)
```

Is there a way I can use one or more calls to `set_check_partial_options` and `check_partials` in order to

- Check `J["x", "a"]` using the cs method, since it's the most exact or demanding,
- Check `J["y", "b"]` using the fd method, since the elliptic functions can't handle complexes,
- Check `J["z", "c"]` using the fd method for the same reason.
- Don't bother checking `J["z", "a"]` at all since it needs to be evaluated using `fd` anyway as there is no analytic formulation possible (at least within scipy).
  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`set_check_partials`](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.15.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/check_partials_settings.html) method to get fine grained control of how the checks are performed. This methods is set inside the `setup` or `setup_partials`of a specific component and lets you control the settings for each input separately.

If you want to set the whole component to CS or FD you can use "*" for the `wrt` argument.

Just be aware that these component level settings get over-written by the `method` argument you pass into the `check_partials`  method itself. So just leave that blank and configure each component with its own local settings.

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug in V3.15 related to `set_check_partials_options`. The following is the correct syntax for the model, but an error is thrown if you uncomment the `cs` option. For V3.15 and less, you'll have to check all with CS or none. It should be fixed by V3.16

```
import openmdao.api as om

from scipy.special import ellipe, ellipk
from scipy.special import hyp2f1

class MWE(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input("a")
        self.add_input("b")
        self.add_input("c")
        self.add_output("x")
        self.add_output("y")
        self.add_output("z")

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        a = inputs["a"]
        b = inputs["b"]
        c = inputs["c"]
        outputs["x"] = a**2
        outputs["y"] = ellipe(b)
        outputs["z"] = hyp2f1(1 / 10, a, 1 / 2, c)

    def setup_partials(self):
        self.declare_partials("x", ["a"], method="exact")
        self.declare_partials("y", ["b"], method="exact")
        self.declare_partials("z", ["a"], method="fd")
        self.declare_partials("z", ["c"], method="exact")


        # self.set_check_partial_options(wrt="a", method="cs") # bug in V3.15
        self.set_check_partial_options(wrt="a", form="backward") 
        self.set_check_partial_options(wrt="b", form="central")

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, J):
        a = inputs["a"]
        b = inputs["b"]
        c = inputs["c"]
        J["x", "a"] = 2 * a

        J["y", "b"] = (ellipe(b) - ellipk(b)) / (2 * b)

        J["z", "c"] = (a / 5) * hyp2f1(11 / 10, 1 + a, 3 / 2, c)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = om.Problem()
    p.model = MWE()

    p.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)

    # set some workable initial values to avoid inf
    p['a'] = 2. 
    p['b'] = -2. 
    p['c'] = -2. 

    p.run_model()
    p.model.list_outputs()

    p.check_partials()
```

Comment: Would you be able to spell out how I should use `set_check_partial_options`? Even with the case of only the outputs `x` and `y`, removing anything related to `z` and the input `c`, I'm having trouble running the checks. 

When I add `self.set_check_partial_options(wrt="a", method='cs')` and
        `self.set_check_partial_options(wrt="b", method='fd')` to `setup_partials` I get an error about `ellipe` in `compute` not knowing how to handle the input type.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for warning about the bug!

Comment: When we looked into this bug, we found that the issue is really that your component is poorly designed for CS. Even if we limited the complex-step to just the one variable of interest, `a`, the `hyp2f1` method still takes that as an argument and is not complex safe. So you just can't safely `cs` this method. We did still modify OpenMDAO to only pass the complex-step to the specific variable of interest. But, again that won't fully fix this component

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. Now that I've realized how this works, I think I have a better idea of the limitations and why they are there. (Since all the computation happens in the same method, it's not possible to avoid putting a complex into hyp2f1 if it's there at all.)